# Call an api with byte array in .NET 6

Tags: arrays, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I did enable Swagger and would like to test an endpoint with input body of datatype `byte[]`.

```
[HttpPost(Name = "publishdata")]
public IActionResult Get([FromBody] byte[] data)
{    
    return Ok();
}
```

And in `RegisterServices` I registered `BinaryConverter`:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(ser =>
    {
        ser.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new BinaryConverter());
       
    });
```

In Swagger, the data type shows as string so I put in something like "11001101101101" and executed. I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "": [
      "The supplied value is invalid."
    ],
    "data": [
      "The data field is required."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "0HMU568RIL38Q:0000000D"
}
```

Can someone help me if there is any additional configuration that I need to add? Or am I doing correctly? I had the same API in .NET 4.8 and it was working fine.

I tried different ways of passing body, changed configuration.

Comment: It'd be better to read the request body via a `Stream` instead of a `Byte[]` btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `System.Text.Json` and custom a `JsonConverter<T>` then it works well,

```
public class ByteArrayConverter : JsonConverter<byte[]>
    {
        public override byte[] Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            short[] sByteArray = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<short[]>(ref reader);
            byte[] value = new byte[sByteArray.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < sByteArray.Length; i++)
            {
                value[i] = (byte)sByteArray[i];
            }

            return value;
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, byte[] value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();

            foreach (var val in value)
            {
                writer.WriteNumberValue(val);
            }

            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }
```

**Models**

```
public class MyModel
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ByteArrayConverter))]
        public byte[] data { get; set; }
    }
```

**endpoint**

```
[HttpPost(Name = "publishdata")]
        public IActionResult Get([FromBody] MyModel model)
        {
            string utfString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(model.data, 0, model.data.Length);
           
            return Ok(utfString);
        }    
    }
```

[image]

Hope this simple demo can give you some help.

Comment: Thank you !! I will try this one today.. I am using Newtonsoft but I can do the same that you did for Json.Net that fit to Newtonsoft convertor.